# Can I claim Segwit2X with a blockchain.info wallet?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, segwit2x

I have a blockchain.info wallet, but I am not sure whether I would be able to claim segwit2x?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited your title to make your question more clear.  Always make sure the title of your question is a brief summary of the question.  It will help attract more and better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the private key. A wallet (irrelevant which wallet) stores your private keys. You will probably not be able to send segwit2x with the blockchain.info-wallet, but you will be able export your private keys of your blockchain.info-wallet and then you can import them into a new segwit2x-wallet.

Comment: Well, that is good news. So I don't have to move my btc to the websites which are partners of Segwit team?

Comment: No. You do only need control over your private keys and that seems to be the case. If they were on an exchange, the exchange had the control over them. By the way: Attention: There are scammers at the moment who try to "save your S2x or your bitcoins". Don't fall for this.

Comment: @Alpha which exchange support Segwit2X? How can I look them up and move my BTC to them so that when it hapens I dont have to worry about private keys and all that stuff?

Comment: As Segwit2X was/is very disputed, I think there is no supporting exchange at the moment. Normally, you must wait at least a week until the first good wallets are realeased or exchanges offer it.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange and wallet supporting b2x but its late already.[image]

Comment: late? What do you mean "late"?